# Where I can see all the methods of a class in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

Eg:- I want to go through the methods which are in ListActivity class. 
In Eclipse when we right click the particular class then  in some options  we can see all the methods of that class. 
How can I do this in Android studio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Project view, you will see something labeled "Structure". If you hit there, you will see all the methods in a given class.

Comment: It is on the left most tab pane in the my ide, the one with words written vertically

Answer (score 3):

Click on "Structure" on the left pane and you will find all the methods listed

[image: Click on structure]

Answer (score 1):

1. First You have to set your keymap as Eclipse in Android Studio. For this go to

   1. File --> Settings. A new window will open
   2. On the left Hand Side Select KeyMap.
   3. Now on the Right Hand Side there is a dropdown Keymaps
   4. select Eclipse.Click Apply then OK

Now you can press `CTRL+Shift+R` and type `ListActivity` to directly open that class. there you will find all the available methods

Another way to see the methods is to

- click in the editor area.
- Click `generate`
- Click Override methods
- There You can see all the available methods that can be overridden